# activerecord performance problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The query below is making trouble in heroku. It takes too long to respond and sometimes it causes application error since heroku has 30 sec timeout limit. Any help will  be appreciated.

```
@entries = Entry.where(:created_at => Time.now-2.day..Time.now).joins("left join training_entries on training_entries.entry_id = entries.id").where(:training_entries => { :entry_id => nil}).order('entries.created_at DESC')



  ←[1m←[36mEntry Load (523.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries` left join training_entries on training_entries.entry_id
 = entries.id WHERE `training_entries`.`entry_id` IS NULL
 AND (`entries`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2011-07-31 21:00:00' AND '2011-08-02 21:00:00') ORDER BY entries.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
0 OFFSET 0←[0m
```

Comment: Could you post the SQL produced by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Index the `created_at` column in `entries` table
- Index the `entry_id` column in `training_entries` table.